# What is the gender of my kitten?

Tags: cats, gender-differentiation

I've looked at so many videos but I'm still unsure.

Here's a picture of the kitten's back end:

> [image: kitty]

Comment: How old is the kitten?

Comment: You'll probably want to see the question: [How do you determine the gender of a kitten?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5879/481). While it doesn't have much for answers yet, there are some comments that should be useful to you.

Comment: Hi Matt, yeah I did have a look I'm still not sure though; he/she is 10 weeks by the way. He/she is going to the vet soon so I'll ask there. Just wanted to know for naming purposes. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Was the picture hidden behind a "spoiler" tag of some sort? `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that's a girl kitten. The distance between the upper and lower openings is fairly close (smaller than the width of the fur-less anal area), and the lower (genital) opening is a "slit" instead of a simple round opening.

The vet will certainly be able to tell. They're very experienced with that kind of thing.